# 'Pyuic4' is not recognized as an internal external command

Tags: cmd, pyqt, external, pyuic

Im trying to compile a ui file by using Pyuic, but i can't get it to work...
Every time i try using the command

> pyuic4 -o OutFile_ui.py InFile.ui

it just givet me this error

> C:\Windows\system32>pyuic4 'pyuic4' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file.

I actually dont't know where the pyuic file should be located, should PyQt, be located within the Python files or something?

Please Help

Comment: to run pyqt you must have installed QT framework

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you install `PyQt`, it gets install under Python's `site-packages`.

There is a batch file `pyuic.bat` under the `<PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR>\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4`. Use this batch to run your command.

If you look into the content of the batch file you will see that it calls the Python interpreter with `PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py` and the given arguments.

Comment: Wait, so it installs itself? i just found a zip file that i have to extract ??

Comment: No first you have to install PyQt4, if you haven't done so.
Check [PyQt4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/)

Comment: I short modification to your answer ... Instead of saying "When you install PyQt, it gets install under Python's site-packages.", it should be, "Install PyQT under your existing Python installation directory e.g. C:\Python\Python3.5". Because, my Python was not installed in C drive

Comment: If you installed pyside, then it's `pyside-uic.exe`

Answer (score 5):

If you add `<PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR>\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4` to you environment path you can run it from any directory by using `c:\pyuic4 input.ui -o output.py`

Comment: this worked  for me ...   at  pyqt5 it is  "pyuic5 input.ui -o output.py"

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert Qt-designer `file.ui` into `file.py` you need to call pyuic4.bat file.

1. Go to python\Lib\site-package from command prompt.
2. type `pyuic4.bat -x file_location\file.ui -o file_location\file.py` then Enter

Answer (score 0):

[sk11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1665093) is right. Do the following:

- Go to `<PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR>\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4`.
- There is a `pyuic4.bat` file in this directory. Copy your .ui file here.
- In cmd, change the directory to `<PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR>\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4`.
- Convert the .ui to .py file using `pyuic4 -x name_of_ui_file.ui -o chosen_name.py`.

This is so basic but it works!