# Error when Converting the Qt Ui file into Python in Windows

Tags: python, qt, cmd, pyqt, qt-designer

**Here are all the commands that i tried but all in vain:**

**1:** E:\python\GUI's> pyuic4 -x first.ui -o first.py

> 'pyuic4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>        operable program or batch file.

**2:** E:\python\GUI's> "C:\QT\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyuic4.bat" -x first.ui -o first.py

> The system cannot find the path specified.

**3:** E:\python\GUI's> "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyuic4.bat" -x first.ui -o first.py

> The system cannot find the path specified

**4:** E:\python\GUI's> "C:\PyQt4_gpl_win-4.12.1\pyuic\uic\pyuic.py" -x first.ui -o first.py

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\PyQt4_gpl_win-4.12.1\pyuic\uic\pyuic.py", line 26, in 
>       from PyQt4 import QtCore ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found'.

**Can anyone tell me what is the main problem or is there another way to do this easily?**

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you install using the Python you are running? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883365/pyuic4-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-external-command and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429452/convert-pyqt-ui-to-python

Comment: I found out that the problem was python version 3.6 installed in my machine, when i deleted it or reinstall the python with version 3.3 then it works, now i can easily convert the file by typing this simple command:

pyuic4 -x first.ui -o first.py

Thanks dear :)